# creating functions and arrays inside d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm attempting to recreate an interactive data visualization found online using d3, but substituting in my own different dataset.

I have a JSON file looks something like this:

```
[{"1993": 22.001,
  "1994": 24.020,
  .
  .
  "2014": 29.010,
  "Country Name": "United States",
  "Indicator Name": "foo"},
{
...
}]
```

In my javascript, I'm attempting to load up the content of the JSON, and create an array containing the values of one year in specific (say, 1993) of any object that matches the "Indicator Name" I'm looking for.

```
d3.json("/static/Data/Untitled.json", function(data) {

            var data_1993 = []
            function select_data(data){
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    if(data[i]['Indicator Name' == 'foo']){
                        console.log(data[i]['1993'])
                        data_1993.push(data[i]['1993'])
                    }
                }
                return data_1993
            }
            select_data(data)
            console.log(data_1993)
```

When I run this, the data_1993 array remains empty. How can I push the data from my json file for a single year into an array, based on a certain condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with your if statement

this:

```
if(data[i]['Indicator Name' == 'foo'])
```

Should be:

```
 if(data[i]['Indicator Name'] == 'foo')
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it must have been a syntax error..